# Do derivative and Integral really cancel out so easily here?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

In a paper I came across the following equation where the loss function $\mathcal{L}$ must be minimized with respect to the reconstruction function $r_\sigma$.
With  $\bar{x} := x + \eta \quad \eta \sim \mathcal{N}(\sigma^2I)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{\textrm{DAE}}(\theta) &= 
\mathbb{E}_{f(\eta, x)} \left[ \|x - r_{\sigma}(\bar{x}) \|^2_2  \right]  \\
 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(\bar{x}-\eta)p(\eta|\bar{x}) \|r_{\sigma}(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta  \|^2_2 \;  d\eta d\bar{x} \\
 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p(\bar{x}-\eta)p(\eta) \|r_{\sigma}(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta  \|^2_2  \; d\eta d\bar{x} \\
&=  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathbb{E}_{\eta} \left[ p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left\|r_{\sigma}(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right \|^2_2 \right] d\bar{x} \quad (1) 
\end{align*}
$$
We minimize this equation by differentiating it with respect to $r_{\sigma}(\bar{x})$ and setting it equal to $0$. Let $r_\sigma^*(\bar{x})$ denote the the minimum:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \mathbb{E}_{\eta } \left[ p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left(r_\sigma^*(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right) \right] \quad(2)
\end{align*} \\
...
$$

My problem is the step between (1) and (2).
Although it looks correct, I failed to do this step more formally.
Any help is much appreciated!

It is the first part of the proof 6.1 from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4246.pdf

**Edit**
Thanks to Milo Brandt's answer I now understand why the integral vanishes. However I am very unsure about the correctness of the  following steps:

Lets fix $\bar{x}$ and try to find a $r$ which minimizes $\mathbb{E}_{\eta} \left[ p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left\|r_{\sigma}(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right \|^2_2 \right] $ for this arbitrary $\bar{x}$. To do so we take the derivativ with respect $r$ and get the minima $r^*$ by setting it to 0.
$$
\begin{align}
0=&\frac{d}{dr}  \mathbb{E}_{\eta} \left[ p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left\|r_{\sigma}^*(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right \|^2_2 \right] \qquad (3) \\
0= &  \mathbb{E}_{\eta} \left[ \frac{d}{dr}  p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left\|r_{\sigma}^*(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right \|^2_2 \right] \qquad (4)\\
0 &= \mathbb{E}_{\eta } \left[ p(\bar{x}-\eta) \left(r_\sigma^*(\bar{x}) - \bar{x} + \eta \right) \right] \quad(4)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: A bit more context would help - there are a real lot of variables here, and it's not exactly clear what their purpose is (e.g. which are involved in the minimization? which are fixed? What are the domains of the various functions involved?) - the more self-contained the question, the easier it'll be to answer. (Might as well specify what paper it's from too, in case a potential answerer might find that useful)

Comment: I think you are confused. The thing you have is an integral with respect to $\bar{x}$.  So it does not depend on $\bar{x}$.  And thus its derivative does not depend on $\bar{x}$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Yes, you are right! I added some more information and linked the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an integral and a derivative cancelling out, so much as an artifact of optimizing over a domain of *functions* - basically, it's a problem involving the calculus of variations.

Without worrying too much about formality, the problem looks something like:

> Find a function $f$ minimizing $L(f) = \int g(x, f(x))\, dx$

And the claim being put forward is essentially that the authors can produce a function $f^*(x)$ with the property that $g(x,f^*(x)) \leq g(x,y)$ for every $x$ and $y$ - or, in words, that $f^*(x)$ minimizes $g(x,-)$ for each $x$. From this, it follows that $L(f^*) \leq L(f)$ for every other function $f$, since the integral on the left hand side is pointwise less than or equal to the integral on the right hand side.

However, this is not what the authors of that paper wrote - perhaps because they wanted to show a derivation of the minimum, rather than just pulling a function $f^*$ out of nowhere and saying "it's got this nice property so it must be the minimum" (although, this is indeed the shortest and perhaps clearest proof of their claim). The form of their argument is somewhat suggestive (though not formally using) of some results that look like a converse to this.

Essentially, if you want to minimize $L(f)$, a good bet is to think about what happens if you slightly perturb $f$ - since the minimum, of course, should not get smaller due to perturbation (or due to anything else, of course!). Informally speaking, if you had some other candidate function $h$, one would expect, as a linear approximation,
$$L(f+\varepsilon h)\approx L(f)+\varepsilon\int g_y(x,f(x))\cdot h(x)$$
where $g_y$ is the derivative of $g$ with respect to its second argument. This is often rigorously true with derivatives, but all the usual analytical details pop up when you try to prove it. In any case, you can see from this that, for $f$ to be a minimum, it really has to be true that
$$\int g_y(x,f(x)) \cdot h(x)=0$$
for *every* function $h$ by which we could perturb $f$. As long as the domain of $L$ is not too constrained and $g$ is not too badly behaved, this just means that
$$g_y(x,f(x)) = 0$$
for every $x$, since otherwise you'd just choose $h$ to be negative where $g_y(x,f(x))$ is positive and positive where $g_y(x,f(x))$ is negative, and find out that perturbing $f$ by that $h$ would decrease $L$ - ruling out $f$ as a minimum. This is why the integral disappears - because we can choose to focus only on any part of the domain by choosing a perturbation wisely - not for any special reason about derivatives and integrals being inverse.

This is more or less analogous to techniques for finding critical points in finitely many dimensions. If you wanted to minimize $f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+f_3(x_3)$ over tuples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, you would just minimize $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_2(x_2)$ and $f_3(x_3)$ separately. What the authors do here is the same, replacing a sum over a finite set with an integral over a continuous domain.

Comment: Thanks you a lot! Now i get the idea, but still lack the ability to write it down formally (I need it for my thesis.) I tried the approach you first described, that is, I took the derivative of (,())  with respect to f(x) via the chain rule and setting it to 0. But this did not yield the desired results.

Comment: @Dulfinator I'm not sure I understand exactly what you describe not working - but the sketch of how I would formally prove the first half of Theorem 6.1 is to start by, in the notation from this post, start by proving that $f^*(x)$ is the minimum of $g(x,-)$ for every fixed $x$ - I didn't look too closely, but that's a one dimensional problem, so should be amenable to calculus or algebra. Is that the troublesome bit? The rest is just saying that for every $f$ then $g(x,f^*(x))\leq g(x,f(x))$ for all $x$ implies $\int g(x,f^*(x))\,dx \leq \int g(x,f(x))\,dx$ which is a common theorem.

Comment: I found it hard to prove without taking the derivative. However, I am not really comfortable with the steps I made. (cf. My Edited answer). Are the steps correct ?Especially (3) to (4)

Comment: @Dulfinator Yeah, that looks fine - the inner term is essentially a polynomial in $r$, so not much can go wrong. If you finish from there, you'll get a fine proof. If you want to avoid justifying some little analytical steps, though, you might note the more general fact that if you wanted to find an $r$ minimizing $\mathbb E[\|r-k\|_2^2]$ for a random variable $k$, the value that does that is just the mean $\mathbb E[k]$. The thing you're minimizing is of that form - where the expectation is with respect to the probability distribution of $\eta$ given the value of $\tilde x = x+\eta$.